# How to define a circle shape in an Android XML drawable file?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

I have some problems finding the documentation of the definitions of shapes in XML for Android. I would like to define a simple circle filled with a solid color in an XML File to include it into my layout files.

Sadly the Documentation on android.com does not cover the XML attributes of the Shape classes. I think I should use an [ArcShape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape) to draw a circle but there is no explanation on how to set the size, the color, or the angle needed to make a circle out of an Arc.

Comment: Here you can read about how to create shape drawable: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: You can get the circle xml from here https://developer.android.com/samples/WearSpeakerSample/res/drawable/circle.html

Comment: The Android Dev documentation has been improved since then. Now it covers `android:shape` element - [Drawable resources](https://d.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape).

Answer (score 1790, accepted):

This is a simple circle as a drawable in Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: And how to change the color dynamically?

Comment: @AnkitGarg you can apply a color filter from Java code (see Drawable class)

Comment: I tried `dp` and it was distorted into an oval shape. For me, using `pt` instead fixed it.

Comment: In some phones if you use the shape as "oval", even setting width and height to the same value, it seems a bit weird. Using "ring" as shape solved the problem to me.

Comment: No need for the `size` in the `shape` if you later define a square size for the view.

Comment: Its shape is oval and not round. Can anyone confirm??

Comment: are u able to add a image in the middle of that circle too?

Comment: @jonney Add a circular image in the same place with margins. Make a new question if you need further help.

Comment: how can i fill the half circle with 2 colors

Comment: @Tarun just set width equal to height, it will show up as a circle

Comment: for changing color of drawable programmatically, you can get the grawable directly by calling getDrawable of layout it has been assigned and then change color from there.

Answer (score 881):

Set this as your view background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#78d9ff"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

For solid circle use:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#48b3ff"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Solid with stroke:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#199fff"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#444444"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

**Note**: To make the `oval` shape appear as a circle, in these examples, either your view that you are using this shape as its background should be a square or you have to set the `height` and `width` properties of the shape tag to an equal value.

Comment: Nice solution. Of course, the oval appears as a circle if the width and height of the view are the same. I think there was a way to make it appear as a circle no matter the size of the view.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch "I think there was a way to make it appear as a circle no matter the size of the view." I solved this using a RelativeLayout wrapping both an ImageView (with the circle as "src" drawable) with fixed width/height and a TextView that wraps a text (for instance).

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing but the circle is drawn as oval

Comment: What if we need it to create around a textview with different border colors at run time ?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I believe you can do that by calling `yourView.getBackground()` and setting the color manually. you need to cast it to a proper type like `ShapeDrawable`. There are related questions on SO about this.

Answer (score 104):

Code for Simple circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477622/4440629, the file needs to go in res/drawable not res/layout

Answer (score 54):

You can use [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="64"
    android:viewportWidth="64">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff00ff"
        android:pathData="M22,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 42,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 22,32 Z" />
</vector>
```

The above xml renders as :

[image]

Comment: Hey, I am having a padding between circle and viewport. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Ajeet you can change the size of viewport and you can put your path inside group and specify the translation and scale `<group android:translateX="-10" android:translateY="15"><path ...`

Comment: @Riyas can you explain the pathData part? what those co-ordinates imply?

Answer (score 46):

Look in the Android SDK samples.  There are several examples in the ApiDemos project:

/ApiDemos/res/drawable/

- black_box.xml
- shape_5.xml
- etc

It will look something like this for a circle with a gradient fill:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
            android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want a **circle** like this

[image]

Try using the code below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 23):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <!-- fill color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <!-- radius -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <!-- corners -->
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: What do the `<corners />` do in an oval (which to my thinking don't have corners)?

Answer (score 22):

Here's a simple circle_background.xml for pre-material:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_accent_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_accent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You can use with the attribute `'android:background="@drawable/circle_background"` in your button's layout definition

Comment: + add 'size' to the shape(s) (depending on usecase).

Answer (score 21):

> a circle shape in an Android XML drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp" />
</shape>
```

> Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 18):

res/drawble/circle_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#e42828"/>
            <stroke android:color="#3b91d7" android:width="5dp"/>
            <!-- Set the same value for both width and height to get a circular shape -->
            <size android:width="250dp" android:height="250dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Try below code with dash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<size
    android:width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:height="@dimen/_60sdp" />

<solid android:color="@color/black" />

<stroke
    android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:color="@color/white"
    android:dashWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:dashGap="@dimen/_1sdp" />
```

Try code without dash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<size
    android:width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:height="@dimen/_60sdp" />

<solid android:color="@color/black" />

<stroke
    android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:color="@color/white" />
```

| Without dash | With dash |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Output without dash] | [image: Out put] |

Answer (score 10):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@color/white"/>

    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/red"
        android:centerColor="@color/red"
        android:endColor="@color/red"
        android:angle="270"/>

    <size 
        android:width="250dp" 
        android:height="250dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't draw a circle inside my ConstraintLayout for some reason, I just couldn't use any of the answers above.

What did work perfectly is a simple TextView with the text that comes out, when you press "Alt+Num7":

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0075bc"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:text="•"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="700"
    android:thickness="100dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

Also, you can adjust the radius of the circle by adjusting `android:thickness`.

[image]

Comment: This is really nice!  It certainly takes some playing with as the attributes are not intuitive.  I managed to get this to display a nice empty circle for a border every time.  And you can use padding to make sure the entire circle displays.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="2"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="@color/button_blue_two" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and you don't have to bother the width and height aspect ratio if you are using this for a textview

Answer (score 6):

First Create Drawable Resource file

[image]

Then Add this Code to the file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       // here define the shape
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
        // here define your color
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
        // here define your shape size
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom drawable to change color and radius of the circle dynamically

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CircleDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Paint circlePaint;
    private int fillColor;
    private int strokeColor;
    private float radius;

    public CircleDrawable(int fillColor, int strokeColor, float radius) {
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        this.radius = radius;
        circlePaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        int x=getBounds().centerX();
        int y=getBounds().centerY();
        //draw fill color circle
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        circlePaint.setColor(fillColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,circlePaint);
        // draw stroke circle
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,circlePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        circlePaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
         circlePaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Set this from UI to get the circle shape

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(new CircleDrawable(Color.RED,Color.YELLOW,100));
```

The Output Will be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/text_color_green"/>
            <!-- Set the same value for both width and height to get a circular shape -->
            <size android:width="250dp" android:height="250dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score -21):

Just use

```
ShapeDrawable circle = new ShapeDrawable( new  OvalShape() );
```

Comment: And how can I set that as the src of an ImageView in my XML layout file?

Comment: This is not directly applicable for an xml layout code

Comment: this is actually works. Thanks :)

val background = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())
                        background.paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.getView().context, R.color.green)
                        val layers = arrayOf(background, resource!!)

                        greenRoundIcon.setImageDrawable(LayerDrawable(layers))