# Android: Drawing circle on screen

Tags: android, android-view, draw, android-bitmap

I'm having trouble drawing a circle to the screen. I do not know if I'm approaching this correctly, or if I have to use a bitmap. Below is a Circle class I created for specifically creating a circle to my specifications.

```
package com.example.alex.parkinsonsdiseaseapp;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class Circle extends View {
    private final float x;
    private final float y;
    private final int r;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public Circle(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setColor(0x000000);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Below is the Activity in which the above class gets used.

```
package com.example.alex.parkinsonsdiseaseapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class FingerTappingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finger_tapping);

        LinearLayout circle = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lt);
        View circleView = new Circle(this, 100, 100, 100);
        circleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        circle.addView(circleView);
        Toast.makeText(FingerTappingActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: whay not xml to draw circle why so much of code???

Comment: you have not specify the width and the height of the `Circle`

Comment: Yeah @Rod_Algonquin is right, you did not specify the `Circle` Views dimensions, so they could be zero, resulting in nothing beeing drawn at all.

Comment: The FrameLayout covers the entire Activity. How to you specify the Circle Views dimensions? @Sandeep I need to write the code because I will eventually make it so that it generates random circles on the screen, just trying to draw one first.

Answer (score 0):

You should set LayoutParams in your CircleView

```
View circleView = new Circle(this, 50, 50, 100)
circleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
circle.addView(circleView);
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the FrameLayout?

Comment: If the FrameLayout (in activity_finger_tapping) is the root of your view there is no problem. If you can't see any effect try to use a LinearLayout

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the import statement for LayoutParams. Android studio makes other suggestions that change that statement.

Comment: import FrameLayout.LayoutParams (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the xml drawable instead if just a circle that you want. Check the answer in [How to define a circle shape in an android xml drawable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file).

After having the xml drawable, create an imageView in your layout and include that as your android:src

With this, you'll not need to worried about LayoutParam etc. You could define it in your imageView and place them accordingly in the position you like in your layout.

*UPDATED*

Hi Alex, as per your need, I have a complete code that generate random circles on the view.

```
public class RandomCircles extends View {

    public int height;
    Context context;
    private Paint mPaint;

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 200;
    private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RandomCircles(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        context = c;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            int x = (int)(Math.random() * w);
            int y = (int)(Math.random() * h);
            int size = (int)(Math.random() * MAX_SIZE);
            addCircle(x, y, size);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Data data : dataList) {
            int size = data.size;
            mPaint.setAlpha(255 - size);
            canvas.drawCircle(data.x, data.y, data.size, mPaint);
        }
    }

    private void addCircle(float x, float y, int size) {
        dataList.add(new Data(x, y, size));
    }


    class Data {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public int size;

        public Data(float x, float y, int size) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a class from it and initiate it in the layout.

```
<com.YOU_PACKAGE_NAME.RandomCircles
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You'll get something like below. Not exactly the same though, as the circle is random. Edit the code as you like to meet your need. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: I'm just trying to display a circle to get my app somewhat functioning. I will need to be able to generate circles at random locations on the screen.

Comment: HI Alex, Add some codes and perhaps that will meet your need.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you are doing, such as the point of using onSizeChanged?

Comment: The onSizeChanged cater for in the event you change your orientation (e.g. portrait and landscape)... and also when initializing, sometime the size do change as you start the activity. i.e. since the size could be match_parent etc... which is not defined in the beginning. Also beginning Android N, the multi window platform allow user to change the size etc. So it's safer to calculate the width and height whenever the size change and reset it.