# "Exception while parsing XML file: Premature end of file." trying to import svg to Android Studio

Tags: android, svg, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to import a `svg` file to Android Studio and I am getting the following error:

> Could not generate a preview
>
> EXCEPTION in parsing prove.svg:
>
> For input string: "60px"Exception while parsing XML file:
>
> Premature end of file.

And this is the `svg` that I have by the moment:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150">
  <circle r="60px" fill="red" cx="90" cy="65"></circle>
</svg>
```

As you can see, I do not have any problems if I use it on the net because it is rendering well.

So, what am I missing? Should I adapt it to some format to use it on Android Studio?

**Note:** I have searched and it seems that it had to be adapted on old versions of `Android Studio` because it did not accept `<circle>` tags but I also have saw that now it should accept them. Now I am using `Android Studio 2.2`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try this SVG approach [here](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_circle):

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Or, the **better** and **scalable** vector approach:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <solid
    android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

HInt: Since the vector method is recommended, there are tools online that can convert SVG to Vector graphics for complex curves and paths.

Comment: Ok, it seems that removing the pixels unit it works well and it does not throw any error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly answer your question but if you want to have a vector based circle in Android, I highly recommend the drawable approach seen in the below answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724737/2680506

Comment: I tried to simplify my code to the most basic element. I have a svg file with more than just one circle. Using the example above it also gives to me the error (I mean with the example that I put  on my question).  Also, I need it on svg and not as a shape.