# I'm trying to create this shape in xml, how to make it?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've linked the image how to create it in android xml

The rounded corners rectangle and circle
The code is written for Getting the circle in rectangle.
I need to create the rectangle with a circle inside. as shown in the image below.

> the code I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Larger blue circle in back -->
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"
                />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"

                />

            <size
                android:width="89dp"
                android:height="22dp"/>

            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#fff" />



        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Smaller red circle in front -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- transparent stroke = larger_circle_size - smaller_circle_size -->
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                android:width="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
            <size
                android:width="5dp"
                android:height="5dp"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="40dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Expected Output]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and explain which part is troubling you. Don't say "all of it", because a simple red circle should be doable for you, assuming you did at least *some* research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a circle shape in an Android xml drawable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185103/how-to-define-a-circle-shape-in-an-android-xml-drawable-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

circle shape can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#B41D1D" />
    <size
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp" />
</shape>
```

The other shape like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FAFAFA" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
    </shape>
```

And then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#E4E4E4"
android:padding="8dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_rectangle"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_circle"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view_rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_rectangle" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you are using API 23 or higher can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Larger blue circle in back -->
<item
    android:width="220dp"
    android:height="56dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius="36dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Smaller red circle in front -->
<item
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:start="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#f00" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I would like to have this code in XML drawable resource file

Comment: I like more the last option but is for API23 or higher, check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList

Comment: Thank you, It was really helpful though!

Comment: how can I add a text to the resource besides the circle?

Comment: If you want to create something more complex you should try with the first option, or maybe with a Custom View, this is a very interesting topic