# Custom View onDraw is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, ondraw

I am creating a Custom TextView where i want to have a circle background and in the middle i want to have the initials of the text. The code is the below

```
class CircleTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {

    private lateinit var circlePaint: Paint
    private lateinit var strokePaint: Paint

    private fun initViews(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
        circlePaint = Paint()
        strokePaint = Paint()
        circlePaint.apply {
            color = Color.parseColor("#041421")
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            flags = Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            isDither = true
        }

        strokePaint.apply {
            color = Color.parseColor("#fe440b")
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            flags = Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            isDither = true
        }
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val diameter: Int
        val h: Int = this.height
        val w: Int = this.width
        diameter = h.coerceAtLeast(w)
        val radius: Int = diameter / 2

        canvas.drawCircle(
            radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), strokePaint
        )
        canvas.drawCircle(
            radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), (radius - 10).toFloat(), circlePaint
        )
        super.draw(canvas)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val dimension = widthMeasureSpec.coerceAtLeast(heightMeasureSpec)
        super.onMeasure(dimension, dimension)
    }

    init {
        initViews(context, attrs)
        setWillNotDraw(false)
    }
}
```

Inside my activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <com.example.ui.views.CircleTextView
        android:id="@+id/circleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /> />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in the Kotlin file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        circleText.apply {
            text = "II"
            setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50)
        }
    }
```

My problem here is that the View seems to gets cropped on the right side of it and also the Text with the letters is not in the Center of the view.

How can i solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main answer to your question is yes: there is an infinite loop on your `onDraw(Canvas)` implementation with your calls to `setWidth(Int)` and `setHeight(Int)` on the `TextView`, which internally call `invalidate()`, which then calls your `onDraw(Canvas)` again to continue the cycle.

You should move all of your `TextView.setXxx(yyy)` calls (`this.xxx = yyy`) outside of your `onDraw` implementation.

For instance, if you want to force your View to have same width and height, you should override `onMeasure` instead:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // This example will always make the height equivalent to its width
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); 
}
```

Setting up your Paints (i.e. `circlePaint.apply { ... }` should be moved to your `initViews` implementation, as they are unchanging.

Since you're only using 1 text color as well, you should also set that value in your `initViews` implementation (or, better, just let it be inherited by the `AttributeSet` used to construct the View).

If you're going to use the TextView's default `setText(String)` anyway (i.e. `this.text = mText`), you may as well just set it directly and drop your custom `mText` entirely:

```
fun setCustomText(value: String) {
    this.text = value.toSplitLetterCircle()
}
```

The same goes for your text size customization:

```
fun setCustomTextSize(value: Float) {
    this.textSize = value
}
```

Both of the above functions then become obsolete, and can be replaced with the standard TextView `setText` and `setTextSize` calls.

To finish, you want to add some number to the radius, which means you actually want the view to be some value larger than it is currently being rendered in. Since you're already using the TextView as your base class, you can use the View's `Padding` properties to add space in between the edges of your View and the start of the content within, e.g.

```
// Order is left, top, right, bottom, units are in px
this.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Which leaves you with:

```
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val h: Int = this.height
    val w: Int = this.width
    diameter = Math.max(h, w)
    val radius: Int = diameter / 2

    canvas.drawCircle(
            (diameter / 2).toFloat(), (diameter / 2).toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), strokePaint
    )

    canvas.drawCircle(
            (diameter / 2).toFloat(), (diameter / 2).toFloat(), (radius - 5).toFloat(), circlePaint
    )

    super.draw(canvas)
}
```

Since all that's left in your `onDraw(Canvas)` are calls to draw 2 circles in the background, you can actually replace it entirely [with a custom background drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724737/1426565), like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#041421"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Which then means you can delete that custom `onDraw(Canvas)` implementation entirely

Edit to answer question part 2:

My initial advice to use the padding without accounting for it in `onMeasure` is incomplete on my part, and could definitely produce the effects you're seeing.

The units passed to `onMeasure(int, int)` are also not true width/height units, but multiple components (size and mode) together that can be accessed via the `MeasureSpec` class. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267248/1426565) goes into much more detail about how that all works. This is important, as it's the reason that your View isn't truly appearing as a perfect square, and the same reason the text isn't centered inside the circle you're drawing.

That then causes `diameter = h.coerceAtLeast(w)` to equal `h` which, according to the screenshot, is larger than `w`, which is why your circle exceeds the bounds on the horizontal plane, but not the vertical.

Also note, you can apply the padding directly in your XML layout as well, using the `android:padding`-related attributes

Comment: The explanation that you gave really helped me and solved me many questions that i had. I followed your advice and now its more clear what and how i am trying to do. However i stuck in another problem and i would be grateful if you could help me! I have edited the question so you can take a look. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! I've updated the answer with some additional info and a link I think should point you in the right direction. Generally, though, if you have new questions that exceed the scope of the original, it's cleaner to create a new question more targeted to the new problem

Comment: Excellent. I almost understood whatever i needed to. Thank you for your valueable comment and explanation!