# How to import Shape class in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

How can I import the class android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape in XML in Android Studio? I'm getting "Cannot resolve class shape".

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
</shape>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there aren't any problem in the code. Why don't you check these things.

1. Did you write the code in res/drawable/something.xml? You have to write your own file name at the `something` part.
2. There isn't `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
</shape>
```

3. Do **Clean, Rebuild Project**.
4. Do **Invalidate Cache/Restart**.

Comment: Thanks! The XML file was not in res/drawable. It was in res/layout. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the drawable folder then new, select drawable resource file
give any file name change that selector to shape and encode the file using UTF-8 like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Shapes should be in the drawable folder